How to write openmp code for nested for-loops
I write an openmp code for several for-loops:

int M=100, N=100;

double U1[M][N];
double U0[M][N];

#pragma omp for private(i,j) shared(M,N, U1, U0)
      for (int i=1; i<M-1; i++)
      {
        for (int j=1; j<N-1; j++)
        {
          U1[i][j] = (U0[i+1][j]+U0[i-1][j]+U0[i][j+1]+U0[i][j-1]);
        }
      }

For this two layer for-loops, shall I add
#pragma omp for

before the second for-loop:
#pragma omp for
for (int j=1; j<N-1; j++)
        {
          U1[i][j] = (U0[i+1][j]+U0[i-1][j]+U0[i][j+1]+U0[i][j-1]);
        }

Is it really necessary to include the declaration
private(i,j) shared(M,N, U1, U0)

after
#pragma omp for 

Would it be an issue if I skip this?
According to the comments, I hope this is correct now.  Thanks.
I try to clean bit the openmp code for several for-loops:

//here U1 U2 are declared outside of the function calling, 
//which has size of M*N=100*100

void openmp_test(const double** U1, double** const U2)
{

  int M=100, N=100;

   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) private(M,N) shared(U1, U2)
    {
      #pragma omp for collapse(2)
      for (int i=1; i<M-1; i++)
      {
        for (int j=1; j<N-1; j++)
        {
          U1[i][j] = (U0[i+1][j]+U0[i-1][j]+U0[i][j+1]+U0[i][j-1]);
        }
      }
}

Here is another correction:
//here U1 U2 are declared outside of the function calling,
//which has size of MN=100100
void openmp_test(const double* U0, double* const U1)
{

  constexpr int M=100, N=100;

   #pragma omp parallel
    {
      #pragma omp for collapse(2) shared (U0, U1)
      for (int i=1; i<M-1; i++)
      {
        for (int j=1; j<N-1; j++)
        {
          U1[i*M+j] = (U0[(i+1)*M+j]+U0[(i-1)*M+j]+U0[i*M+j+1]+U0[i*M+j-1]);
        }
      }
}


omp for outside of a omp parallel region is useless (no effect). Thus, you should add parallel to your omp for inless the function is called from a parallel section. There is no need to add a #pragma omp for in the second loop. This is actually a bad idea (cause issues without benefits). If you want the too loops to be parallelized, then you can add a collapse(2) clause on the omp for. Generally, it is not a good idea unless you know that the first loop does not provide enough parallelism (or may not on all the target platforms)

private(i,j) is useless here since j is declared in the loop and so its scope is local to the inner loop and i is automatically considered private by OpenMP since the loop is parallelized. By default, variables declared outside a parallel section are automatically shared inside a parallel section but there are AFAIR some exceptions (especially when you mix your code with tasks). Here, it is not clear whether U0 and U1 are in a parallel section. Can you clarify this point? If they are, then they are automatically private and I think they should not be marked shared here.

Last but not least, note that tiling is critical for stencil to be efficient (especially in the time dimension is possible). Note that OpenMP offers some directives for tilling though they are quite recent so IDK if compilers implement them. Writing efficient stencil is actually hard and they are libraries and tools to do it properly.

thanks a lot!  U0 and U1 are shared memory that are accessed by all the threads because I want to updates U1  by all threads. In this case, shall I declare it as shared ?

Yes, you can declare them as shared though they may already regarding the exact specific code. You just need to be sure the scope of the variable is not large enough which is usually the case (for more information please share a minimal reproducible example).

Hi, I tried to rewrite the code according the suggestions. I have posted in the question above. Please let me know if there is still something wrong there. Thanks

This seems fine to me overall for the OpenMP part. Note that private(M,N) can be removed here: it will ba shared but this is not a problem as long as you do not change the value. You can also mark M and N as const (or even constexpr in C++). Marking in private is just a security. shared(U1, U2) is useless here since it is shared by default but doing that explicitly is not wrong. Marking variable explicitly can be actually good to avoid mistakes. num_threads(4) is generally not a good idea. Consider setting the env variable OMP_NUM_THREADS instead (more flexible).

Note that U1 and U2 (which should be U0 and U1 for the function to build) are not contiguous arrays but jagged arrays. Jagged arrays tend to be slower. It is better for performance to flatten the array and deal with the double* type. This means access will be U0[i*M+j] rather than U0[i][j]. This is very common in HPC applications to do that. AFAIK double U0[M][N]; is always contiguous internally (and double[][] should not be confused with double**).

Your comment are really helpful.  I just made the corrections in the code posted in the question above. Thanks a lot.
